# Excel - conditionally hide errors

Tags: excel, if-statement, error-handling, formula

I cannot figure out how to hide an error (or even why they're showing up in the first place). I have a formula starting in row 3 where I'm checking for matching values in a cell, then doing another formula based on the bool response. When I drag it down the column into the other rows, the next row looks good (shows blank) but every row after that shows an error. I tried using `=IFERROR()` and `=ISERROR` but cannot figure it out. The main formula in the cell is `=IF(D3=D2, G2+E3,IF(D3="","",E3))` starting in row 3. How can I add something to the formula to hike the errors? Or if someone can explain why I'm getting them in the first place?

[image: sheet screenshot]

Comment: "How can I add something to the formula to hike the errors" - `IFERROR([formula],"")`

Comment: Ahhh...I was trying it at the end, not at the beginning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use your formula, without any errors.  The thing you want to make sure is that your data in E and G are formatted as `Time`.  (but it seems to be working for me in any format. I'd just do `Time` to be safe).

I also slightly tweaked your formula, but it should do the same: `=IF(D2="","",IF(D2=D1,G1+E2,E2))`. I put that in `G2` and dragged down:

[image]

But, in any case, you could use `IFERROR()` to hide an error.  `=IFERROR([your formula],"")`.  (Obviously, you can replace the `""` with anything, such as `"ERROR, check values"`, etc.)

Final tip - if you want to see where the `#VALUE` error comes from, step through the formula in `Formulas -> Evaluate Formula`, with that cell selected:

[image]

So, since `D7` is empty, and `D6` is empty, the next part of the formula is run, `G6+E7`. But! Notice how your `G6` cell is `""`, but `E7` is empty. You can't add a "string to empty", so it returns a value error.

By first checking if the cell in column D is blank (as I did with my tweak), you can avoid this altogether, without needing `IFERROR()`.